# Using gradef with complex quantities in Maxima

Tags: operator-precedence, complex-numbers, maxima, differentiation, wxmaxima

I'm using `gradef` to declare the gradients of certain complex variables (that depend on an independent variable, say, `t`) in terms of other complex variables dependent on the same independent variable.

But I'm running into some issues while applying the `realpart` or `imagpart` commands. For example, I expect `(%o5)` and `%(o4)` to match in the following but it doesn't.

[image]

Here's the maxima code for convenience:

```
declare([A,B],complex)$
depends([A,B],t)$
gradef(A,t,diff(B*exp(%i*t),t));
realpart(diff(A,t));
diff(realpart(A),t);
```

I have a feeling that this is somehow related to operator precedence between `diff` and `realpart` but I'm unable to get the correct substitution to work. I also tried,

```
diff(realpart(A),t));
ev(%,nouns);
```

but this doesn't work either.